# Is the holocaust divine punishment for the wrongs Jews have done?

Tags: holocaust-shoah

Just wanted an evaluation of this question from a Jewish standpoint.

Comment: Reminds of the conversation purported to have taken place between the Satmar Rebbe & the Lubavitcher Rebbe post Shoah. Also, relates to the disagreement between some about the concept of reward & punishment as discussed in Moreh Nevuchim.

Comment: Short answer - yes. However, the long answer is both long and complicated. We can try and guess which particular sins contributed in part by taking into account the principle of Midah k'neged Midah. Note also, the Holocaust in many ways is a perfect echo of the Tochacha.

Comment: There is no single "evaluation from a Jewish standpoint" regarding why the Holocaust happened. It will depend who you ask. Some will say it happened because of 'x', some will say we can't know why it happened. It should be noted that the former kind of explanation is meant on a national level only, but not on an individual level; it's not meant to explain why any particular individual died, only why tragedy befell the Jewish people as a whole.